# BLE112 - BLED112 and Win7 Communication

Tags: .net, windows-7, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluegiga

I am using BLE112 and BLED112 for my project. I want to send some data from BLE112 which
is mounted on my PCB to the BLED112 USB Dongle plugged in my Windows 7 machine. I have connected to BLE112 by BLED112 over BLEGUI therefore my hardware is working properly.

My problem is I want to read the data received by BLED112 through my .Net application.

So can you answer my following questions or if you have any other idea about how to read BLED112 easily from Windows 7 please let me know.

- Can BLED112 work standalone and send the data over USB to the PC? And can I read these data from Virtual Serial Port?
- Is there any .Net library that I can use directly. (I know there is a Java Lib)
- Do I have to only use BGLib implemented on BGAPI to read data from BLED112.

Thanks..

Answer (score 3):

I found this C# wrapper for the BlueGiga API on gitHub last week, when I was in your situation: https://github.com/ahouben/BleDriver.NET

I have successfully adapted and integrated it into my application. It is running up against a TI CC2541 without problems (so far...).

I have also tested it with the latest API XML (ble-1.1.1-77) from BG, and the Python script (which generates the C# class) works equally fine with that one.

Comment: Thank you I will try this lib. but I have a question. As you know BLE and BLED112 use TI CC2540 chip. The only diffrence between 2540 and 2541 is 2540 supports USB communication. Dou you think that is this going to be a problem?

Comment: Just to clarify: I am using the BleDriver.NET with the BLED112 - just as you do - and I am using it to connect to a device which uses the TI CC2541.

Comment: Hi there, I have a similar issue. The issue is I have a bluegiga bluetooth dongle and a bluetooth calliper. I want to get data from the calliper through an existing C# desktop application. The desktop application runs on Windows 8 and 8.1, but it is just a windows desktop application. I am able to use the BleDriver.NET to open the dongle's port but I can not connect with the calliper. Can you advise me on what to do?